# Python: smart way to lowercase transformation of key values from an array of JSON

Tags: python

I am trying to do lowercase data transformation. My input data are in the following format

```
ret = { "users":[
             {"EMAIL":"jogn@doe.com","Name":"John Doe"},
             {"EMail":"james@black.com","nAme":"James Black"}
             ]
}
```

and the output should be something like

```
ret = { "users":[
                 {"email":"jogn@doe.com","name":"John Doe"},
                 {"email":"james@black.com","name":"James Black"}
                 ]
    }
```

What I did is :

```
users = ret['users']
new_array = []
for item in users:
    for key in item:
        k = key.lower()
        new_array.append({k:item[key]})
```

and the result is what I expected but I was wondering if there is a smart and better way to achieve this task. Is there a way to avoid the double loop?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to loop over each dict in the list, and each item in the dict. You can play around with the format like using comprehensions, but in one form or another you're looking at two for loops. (And there's nothing wrong with that.)

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your original solution is already very readable, you could also try using list comprehensions:

```
ret = { "users":[
                 {"EMAIL":"jogn@doe.com","Name":"John Doe"},
                 {"EMail":"james@black.com","nAme":"James Black"}
                ]
      }

ret['users'] = [dict((k.lower(), v) for k, v in d.items()) for d in ret['users']]

>>> print(ret)
{'users': [{'email': 'jogn@doe.com', 'name': 'John Doe'}, {'email': 'james@black.com', 'name': 'James Black'}]}
```

Additionally, It's probably safer to just rebuild a new dictionary with all values updated, than to overwrite the original data. This can be demonstrated below:

```
result = {}

# Can be a another one-liner, but then it becomes unreadable
for key, value in ret.items():
    result[key] = [dict((k.lower(), v) for k, v in d.items()) for d in value]

>>> print(result)
{'users': [{'name': 'John Doe', 'email': 'jogn@doe.com'}, {'name': 'James Black', 'email': 'james@black.com'}]}
```

If you really want the one liner to the second part:

```
result = dict((key, [dict((k.lower(), v) for k, v in d.items()) for d in value]) for key, value in ret.items())
```

Comment: useful if we want not to override the original data.

Comment: Yep definitely, it depends what you're doing with your JSON data. I hope this answer helped.

Comment: Sure!. thanks a lot. Basically, data comes from a CVS file and I want to be sure that all the keys are lowercase when I store them.

Comment: out of curiosity, in your opinion, is my way acceptable or it is just too simple (or just not python's style), to be used?

Comment: No problem, do you mean *"CSV"* here? Yeah I think rebuilding the dictionary with lowercase keys after you store the original data is the safest approach. Like you said, you don't want to overwrite the original data if you can help it.

Comment: Your way is the most readable, and straightforward in my opinion. Also very pythonic. The way I showed above does the job in a condensed manner, but it takes a while to understand what exactly is going on. Your way is clear from looking at it for a couple of seconds. Its your choice in the end, though.

Comment: No worries :). If you liked one of answers given, make sure to give it a green tick, just for future users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160626/discussion-between-roadrunner-and-hellbreak).

Answer (score 2):

Complex one liner (surely not smart; just a fancy way):

```
>>> ret = { "users":[
             {"EMAIL":"jogn@doe.com","Name":"John Doe"},
             {"EMail":"james@black.com","nAme":"James Black"}
             ]
}
>>> lower_cased = {k.lower():[{dk.lower():dv for dk,dv in d.items()} for d in v] for k,v in ret.items()}
>>> lower_cased
{'users': [{'email': 'jogn@doe.com', 'name': 'John Doe'}, {'email': 'james@black.com', 'name': 'James Black'}]}
```